# SQL get back the wrong @@identity

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_FinancialInstitutionsAdd]
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
    set nocount on

    begin tran
        declare @retval int = 0
        declare @rmdID int

        execute @rmdID = dbo.sp_MetaDataRecsAdd   

        select @rmdID as rmdID

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            rollback tran
            return -1
        end

        insert FinancialInstitutions (Name, rmdID)
        values (@Name, @rmdID)

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            rollback tran
            return -1
        end

        return scope_identity()
        commit tran
```

I can only get back the ID of the inserted `MetaDataRecs` table but I want the ID of the `FinacialInstitutions` table. The procedure works fine when executed directly in SQL but not when executed with a `ExecuteScalar` command from code.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

First, unless you use a really old sql server version, you should use [`Try...catch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.90).aspx) instead of that old style `if @@ERROR <> 0`. Sql server supports Try...catch since 2005 version.
Second, I suspect you get the wrong Identity from the `scope_identity()` function because it's not included in the transaction. I'm not sure what should it return if the transaction is rolled back.
Try this:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_FinancialInstitutionsAdd] 
(
    @Name varchar(50),
    @ReturnValue int output
)
AS
set nocount on

declare @rmdID int, 
        @retval int = 0

begin Try
    begin tran

    execute @rmdID = dbo.sp_MetaDataRecsAdd   

    -- select @rmdID as rmdID -- What is that row? I've commented it out since it makes no sense to me
    
    insert into FinancialInstitutions (Name ,rmdID)
    values (@Name ,@rmdID)
 
    set @ReturnValue = scope_identity()
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran
end catch
```

**Note #1**: You will need to change your call to this procedure to add the @ReturnValue as an output parameter.

**Note #2**: If this procedure will encounter an error before this line `set @ReturnValue = scope_identity()`, the value of `@ReturnValue` will remain `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: When this proc is run from sql query, it works fine.  When it is run with executescalar, it returns null. (but the table updates happen.)

Comment: that's because [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not return the return value of the procedure, but the first value or row returned by the select statement. you don't have a select statement in your procedure. See my edited answer.

Comment: Replace set @ReturnValue = scope_identity()

Comment: @kunstena I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Also, take marc_s's advice - don't use sp_ as a prefix to your stored procedure. +1 to marc for noticing that.

Answer (score -1):

Both the @@identity and the scope_identity() are going to return you the last id that was created.
This is also a problem for people that use triggers that insert something into another table.

I don't know your table but I'd do something like

```
declare @id int
select @id = max(id) from FinancialInstitutions 
return @id
```

cheers

Comment: Downvote reason: this answer is wrong. Scope_identity() will return the last identity in the scope it's executed in. it will not return an identity created by a trigger if it's executed in a stored procedure. [read here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Did you try it before downvoting?

Comment: *Did you?*
Read the article I've linked. There is a reason why it's called scope_identity().

Comment: [Just for you, Here is a live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d9f12/2) of the difference between @@identity and scope_identity().

Answer (score -1):

1. As per my understanding you are relying on old methodology of handling errors.
   Try to use TRY..CATCH block for readability and good practicing design.
2. Also don't use RETURN to return Identity value to the caller, good practice is to declare OUTPUT parameter for this purpose.

Comment: downvote reason: this answer doesn't add any information I didn't cover in my answer, 6 hours before you posted yours.